# Sending parameters to Jasper Report and exporting to .docx without database

Tags: java, jasper-reports, docx

I am having a really hard time even finding correct up to date information on this. Most of the information I find uses deprecated methods that no longer are used.

My program allows the user to search the database for a person, click the person they want within the table, it loads the row of data from the table, and stores it to an array. The array is then broken up into variables, and then passed to this PrintCertificate() class, in which all of the parameters are passed into the .jrxml Jasper Report I created in the Studio, and fill in the parts of the certificate that are empty.

```
 package print;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.*;
 import java.util.*;

public class PrintCertificate  
{   
public PrintCertificate(String output, String certType, String name, String pNames, String bapDate, String confirmDate, String pastorName, String sponsorName)
{
    if(certType=="rci_eng")
    {
        String fileName = "/RCI_Eng";
        output = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test/";

        HashMap<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        param.put("Full_Name",name);
        param.put("Parent_Names", pNames);
        param.put("DateOfBaptism", bapDate);
        param.put("PastorName", pastorName);
        param.put("SponsorName", sponsorName);
        try
        {
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(fileName, param);

            JRDocxExporter exporter = new JRDocxExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "test.docx");
            exporter.exportReport(print);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

}

I obviously know alot of this is already not right, including the output and OUTPUT_FILE_TYPE, but I need to know if im on the right track and if theres anything I can use to make this easier.

Comment: There are lots of ways you can make this work, this is one. If you have a database, you might consider allowing Jasper Reports to fill out the form from the query itself

Answer (score 0):

The question, *if im on the right track?* is a bit broad

You can use the **parameter map***, you can use a **query** from with jasper report (see @MadProgrammer comment), you can pass directly your `PrintCertificate` **class** as datasource.

*Note: with **parameter map**  you will not put any data in detail band and you can only create 1 certificated.

*Which is best?*, executing query within jasper report  or passing parameters probably have the advantage of preview during development of report, hence you can set default values; using `PrintCertificate` class as datasource has the advantage of that you can easily format/handle output (since jasper will call methods in class).

The **"normal" way** would be executing a query  inside jasper report passing the `idperson` as a parameter (hence the query will  find 1 record, relative to the person you like to view). The fields are  autogenerated by IDE, you can easily test it for different persons, you can easily change the query to export multiple certificates ecc.

But in the end the choose is yours...

*Where are you not on the right track?* (and this is the reason that I answer)

[JRExporterParameter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporterParameter.html) is **deprecated** since jasper version 5.6

The correct way since this version would be:

```
JRDocxExporter export = new JRDocxExporter();
export.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
export.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new File("test.docx")));

SimpleDocxReportConfiguration config = new SimpleDocxReportConfiguration();
//config.setFlexibleRowHeight(true); //Set desired configuration
export.setConfiguration(config);

export.exportReport();
```